# Prevent access to a specific view in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, .htpasswd

I am developing a website with CakePHP.
I have an `AdminsController` for admins to authenticate. However I want create extra security by adding .htaccess password protection.

I tried to do it by adding `.htaccess` and a `.htpasswd` files in my Admins view directory since I want the other pages of my site to work normally, but it doesn't work.
So how to add `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` for only a specific view?

In my AdminsControllers's beforeFilter method I've added :

```
if(env('HTTP_HOST') == 888.888.888.888 || ......),
```

The list of IP addresses that should be allowed. Can I say that it is safe now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to investigate the other authentication components that CakePHP has to offer.  [BasicAuthenticate](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/basic-authenticate) should be of particular interest.

If you go down this route, the authentication will still happen against a userModel rather than a .htpasswd file.

As for the IP restriction, that should be relatively safe.  IP spoofing is possible but hard.